# ARToolkit Demo for Android not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, artoolkit

I’m trying to get into AR and therefore downloaded the ARToolkit SDK for Android from here: http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_about

However, when I import the examples into eclipse, I’m having tons of errors, telling me that multiple classes (like ARActivity or ARRenderer for example) cannot be resolved to a type.
Within the project, I see the armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips and the x86 folder within the libs folder.
Do I need anything else? (like adding a JAR to the Build Path?)
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Within the example-folder, there is also a ARBaseLib-project. I added this to the Build Path of my ARSimple project, and now it's working.

Comment: Ah, yes, the ARBase project is the NDK wrapper for the jniLibs.

Comment: The project structure It is explained here: http://www.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_developing